# MYSQL count related records one query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

So i have a mysql query that queries a table "contacts" each contact then has purchases. Purchases are in a related table. I want to display each contacts name with the number of purchases they have made to the right like this:

```
Adam(1)
Mike(8)
Steve(3)
```

My current sql looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY contacts.name ASC"
```

and my current table looks like this:

```
Adam
Mike
Steve
```

In order to pull the count of the related (purchases) table into the current table i know i have to join the "purchases" table some how and then use the GROUP BY and count() function but i am not sure how to construct this sql statement.  Can someone help me.

Again all i am trying to do is list a table (contacts) and count it's related records (purchases) and have it look like this:

```
Adam(1)
Mike(8)
Steve(3)
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming the `purchases` table has a foreign key to the `contacts` table called `contact_id`, a query something like this should work:

```
SELECT c.name, count(p.contact_id)
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases AS p
ON p.contact_id = c.contact_id
GROUP BY c.contact_id
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

This query will put the count in a separate column, which I recommend. If you must format it the way you indicated with the parentheses after the name, you can use MySQL's [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function. Something like this:

```
SELECT concat(c.name, '(', count(p.contact_id), ')') AS Name_And_Count_Together
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases AS p
ON p.contact_id = c.contact_id
GROUP BY c.contact_id
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked like a charm.  Glad i posted in here bc i would have never figured that out on my own.  Thank you again.

Comment: It's possibile to add the date of the last purchase to the first query?

Comment: @ipel Sure. You can add something like max(p.purchase_date) to the select list.

Comment: If you're wondering if LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same, they are according to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425740/are-left-outer-joins-and-left-joins-the-same

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT contacts.name, COUNT(*) 
    FROM contacts, purchases 
   WHERE contacts.name = purchases.name
GROUP BY purchases.key
ORDER BY contacts.name
```

Replace .name in the WHERE clause with the key you are using to identify records.

Comment: An outer join would be advisable so that you can include contacts with zero purchases too.

Answer (score 0):

The required query would be something like this (I don't know your schema):

```
SELECT c.name, count(p.id) FROM contacts c
JOIN purchases p ON (c.id = p.id)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY contacts.name ASC
```

Comment: An outer join would be advisable so that you can include contacts with zero purchases too.