# Are left outer joins and left joins the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen joins called LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN. In some places I have seen LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN. I am confused by this.

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377552/how-many-types-of-joins-are-there-in-mysql-or-sql)  2 days ago, but I am unable to understand the links the solutions provide.

Are these types of joins both the same, or is there some difference between the two?

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is the same as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. `OUTER` keyword is *optional*.

Comment: @JW. i saw the link whatever you suggested .It is very useful.But it still did not fulfill all my doubts. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @JW. i have another question for u

Comment: @jw. i want to learn writing some complex queries using joins and cases.Can u refer some links for that.I saw your answers.They attracted me very well.Can u give some reference sites for that.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are no difference between both.
Refer [visual represenation of joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: This article is just awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

The first link they quoted gives you:

`INNER JOIN`: returns rows when there is a match in both tables.

`LEFT JOIN / LEFT OUTER JOIN`: returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table.

`RIGHT JOIN / RIGHT OUTER JOIN`: returns all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table.

`FULL JOIN / FULL OUTER JOIN / OUTER JOIN`: returns rows when there is a match in one of the tables.

`SELF JOIN`: is used to join a table to itself, as if the table were two tables, temporarily renaming at least one table in the SQL statement.

`CARTESIAN JOIN`: returns the cartesian product of the sets of records from the two or more joined tables.

The `self join` is actually not a `special join`. It just reflects the fact that you can join a table with itself. Doing so you must alias it in order to address the fact that it appears more than once in the same statement.

The `cartesian join` can be considered as an `inner join` without a restricting condition. Or you may view an `inner join` as a `cartesian join` with an added restriction (the join condition).

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the manual page for [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) you will see the following lines:

```
join_table:

   table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]

   | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor

   | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
```

| **table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition**

```
   | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
```

The bold line clearly shows that the keyword OUTER is optional.

Comment: @Luv - Now the final line does not make sense with your formatting!

Comment: If it's optional it does not means it doing nothing. This **optional** word in SQL descriptions confusing me a lot. For example standard `git log` CLI command syntax: `git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>…​]` a plenty of optional arguments. But that have significant influence on the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL syntax, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` are identical: (from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
| table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
| table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
```

Note that the `OUTER` keyword is optional for LEFT/RIGHT JOIN.

LEFT and RIGHT joins are both outer joins.  I believe there are some flavors of SQL that may require the `OUTER` keyword, but MySQL does not.  That is to say that at times `LEFT JOIN` may not be valid.

Answer (score 2):

I am working in SQL Server and as per my usage and experience there is absolutely no difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The same is true for `RIGHT JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. When you use `LEFT JOIN` keyword in SQL Server, it means `LEFT OUTER JOIN` only.
So as per my opinion its the generic rule which is same for all database engines.

[see here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/22/sql-server-differences-between-left-join-and-left-outer-join/) and [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/#comment-112416)