# Mysql union select error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display all records from *table1* even if the `catid` not existing in *table2* (all employee in *table2* should have all `catid` from *table1* with 0 days if not exising in *table2*) with the following sql query but getting an error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'catid' in 'group statement'

```
select empid,days from table2 union select catid from
table1 group by empid, catid;
```

table1:

```
catid
  1
  2
  3
```

table2:

```
empid catid days (computed column count(*))
1000    1    8
1000    3   10
```

expected result:

```
empid  catid  days
1000    1    8
1000    2    0 <---catid 2 and days 0 if catid not existing in table2 for empid 1000
1000    3   10
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the function of the union statement. Union statement does a set like capability which merging two sets. What you are looking for a is a join with the table 1 where you do a count and group by catid. Your data model to achieve this output itself is grievously wrong ;)

```
select employeeid, catid, sum(days) from table1, table2 group by employeeid, catid;
```

Comment: this retrieves all catid from table1 and also the empid but days are all same value. Actually days are count(*) not an actual column in table2

Answer (score 0):

**You just need a `LEFT JOIN`:**

```
    Select tab2.empid, tab2.catid, ifnull(tab2.days, 0)
    from tab2 
    left join tab1 on tab2.catid = tab1.catid
```

**Please note :** While doing a **UNION the number and type of the columns present in the first select should be the same as the next Selects**.

**So you need to first make the select columns in sync first.**

Answer (score 0):

can you check this and add *empid* similarly.

```
SELECT TABLE1.CATID, IFNULL(TABLE2.DAYS,0) FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
table2 ON table1.catid = table2.catid
```

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425740/are-left-outer-joins-and-left-joins-the-same

Answer (score 0):

**Please use LEFT JOIN with IFNULL**.

```
Select table2.empid, table1.catid, IFNULL(table2.days, 0) from table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.catid = table1.catid;
```

Comment: NVL is not there in MYSQL

Comment: You are right  Sashi Kant. Should have used IFNULL.

Comment: Please edit once again, since it is not allowing me to undo the down vote.